# Plotting values from different dataframes side by side within same group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two dataframes (Foo and Bar) that each look like this:

```
Group    AME    lower    upper
  A       .       .        .
  B       .       .        .
  C       .       .        .
```

Both Foo and Bar have the same number of groups and the groups have the same names, but the values under "AME," "lower" and "upper" are different in each. Currently, I'm displaying the data in Foo and Bar on separate plots such that the Y axis of each plot is the group, the X axis is the value listed for that group under "AME", and "lower" and "upper" determine the bounds of an error bar for that value. Here is my code:

```
ggplot(aes(x=Group, y=AME)) + 
geom_point() +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower,ymax=upper),width=0)+
geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color="gray", linetype="longdash")+
coord_flip()
```

However, what I'd like to do is display the data in both dataframes on the same plot like shown below:
[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already outlined in the comments bind your data by rows and use `position_dodge`.

Using some fake example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

foo <- data.frame(
  Group = LETTERS[1:3],
  AME = 1:3,
  lower = 0:2,
  upper = 2:4
)

bar <- data.frame(
  Group = LETTERS[1:3],
  AME = rev(1:3),
  lower = rev(0:2),
  upper = rev(2:4)
)

pd <- position_dodge(width = .6)

dplyr::lst(foo, bar) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "Key") |>
  ggplot(aes(y = Group, x = AME, shape = Key)) +
  geom_point(position = pd) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin = lower, xmax = upper), width = 0, position = pd) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2, color = "gray", linetype = "longdash")
```

[image]